# How to import dxf file

Tags: import

I want to import autocad dxf file and i have activated the addon and its giving error :
**Minimum version dxf12(ac1009) not met. version found ac1002**

How to import the file is there any other addon or whats the other way to import

Comment: You should say what type of .dxf file you saved for this question to have meaning. It might also be helpful to know what application the original file was made in. Dxf like Stl can mean different things to different software.